# Replace a Link to a file per GScript in GMail

Tags: google-apps-script, replace, hyperlink, gmail

Due to a data migration between two domains, the IDs of the files have changed.

Is it possible with  GScript to search in a GMail that I forward or reply to and replace a URL to a Google file. In a separate table I have an overview "oldID" <> "newID".

One example:

This URL:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/10IXFzXXXpEPW6X2W6nXWVJX_hXdrgc0IivDnTF-I1_c

becomes this URL:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ByuyeidXxXN3WxXRK-NFoaYubVAXXAQU4_vtBzgFK99

My primary question is whether this is possible and if so, which approach should I take?

Greetings

I am still looking for a starting point.

Comment: If you're trying to edit a message in Gmail, then no it's not possible.

Comment: I agree that the Gmail API used in Google Apps Script can do read-only, thus it can't update/edit existing email messages for you to be able to replace the URLs. Upon further diving in other posts, [this existing accepted answer from a similar post could be your option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63397569).